# When auto generating database.cs with Peta Poco how do I account for composite keys

Tags: c#, orm, petapoco

I am currently generating a database.cs file using Peta Poco and am hitting a problem with a composite key. In one of the tables.

This error is displayed:

```
Error   3   Running transformation: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
```

^^ I would have posted an image but I need more reputation lol.

I am wondering if there is a way to make Peta Poco account for this type of composite key?

ty for any help given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Not without editing the file that generates the database.cs file. Sorry for the post :)